# How to stop "tab" key indenting whole line

Tags: vimrc, indentation, insert-mode

In one version of VIM that I run, when I hit the "tab" key in insert mode, it indents the whole line, regardless of the cursors position in the line.

Here is what I believe to be the only modified parts of the config, however I can include more as necessary (the whole file is 296 lines so I'll need to cut it down).

```
set nowrap

set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set tabstop=4

filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: That sounds like a mapping (maybe something like `inoremap <tab> <c-o>>>`) you should following the instructions in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) and edit your question with what you'll find.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging link. I followed the instructions and found out that your guess was almost spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment from @statox♦ I was able to find the line of my code causing this. Using the debug method in the link showed me that it was the line (which was close to @statox♦'s original suggestion):

```
inoremap <Tab> <C-T>
```

Commenting this out fixed my issue.